# Checking if Viewbag property is empty, and using default value in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this piece of code in a MVC view that works, but it seams like a lot of code to achieve this simple thing. Any way to make it more efficient?

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Name))
{
 @:&nbsp;    
}
else
{
 @:ViewBag.Name
}
```

Comment: I have to warn about one thing in my answer. If the ViewBag.Name is "" then you get the output as "" not &nbsp;. It's because the ?? operator only works for null and not empty strings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
@(ViewBag.Name ?? Html.Raw("&nbsp;"))
```

Answer (score 5):

> Any way to make it more efficient?

Yeah sure, use view models and get rid of the `ViewBag`:

```
public string FormattedName
{
    get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name) ? " " : this.Name; }
}
```

and then in your strongly typed view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FormattedName)
```

or if you prefer:

```
@Model.FormattedName
```

Another possibility is to write a custom helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Format(this HtmlHelper html, string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            return new HtmlString("&nbsp;");
        }

        return html.Encode(name);
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.Format(Model.Name)
```

or if you need to keep the ViewCrap you will have to live with a cast (sorry, .NET doesn't support extension method dispatch on dynamic parameters):

```
@Html.Format((string)ViewBag.Name)
```

Comment: I think `dynamic` in general is overused.